# center a percentage based element

Tags: html, css

I've seen some people do this but it doesnt quite seem the same I want to center this percentage based div in the middle of my screen and make it responsive. I did fixed but responsive would be better any ideas? The percentage for height=50% width=60%

Comment: It's best to post an example of something you've tried in order to accomplish this. i.e. what have you seen tried, and what doesn't it seem the same as?

Comment: This is what I had for the fixed version, I tried a little of the solution but I went back to fixed so I cant copy that here. 
.center{
    
    height: 600px;
    width: 700px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-left: -350px;
    text-align: center;
    
    

}

Comment: This is what I have now after the suggestion and its working ,
.center{
    
    height: 50%px;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    

}

Comment: Heres what I'm doing,

http://jhodges11.aisites.com/IMD212/public_html/landing.html 

Im looking at it on two different machines and it looks drastically different so how does this look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform`. It allows you to center everything without know his sizes.

```css
 /** that's the trick **/
.centered {  
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}


/* only for snippet **/
.yellow {
  background:yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.red {
  z-index:0;
  background:red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered yellow"></div>
<div class="centered red"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I had something similar to this but it wasnt working at first

Answer (score 0):

```
left: 20%;
top: 25%;
```

and this only works if the surrounding container (body?) has valid `height` and `width` settings